Redux useSelector not logging state in console - Issue with habits state in React app
I am trying to learn redux code by implementing the below tutorial
I am not able to see the console log for habits in the browser
providing my code snippet below
can you let me know how to fix it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ovliZG617g&t=1310s
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/yxtwjg?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Fhabits-list.tsx%3A9%2C6
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "../store/store";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";

const HabitList: React.FC = () => {
  const { habits } = useSelector((state: RootState) => {
    state.habits;
  });
  return <Box>{console.log("habits", habits)}</Box>;
};

export default HabitList;


Put the console.log in the body of the function component, not in the return.  And unless your state is structured like this {habits:{habits:"stuff"}} I don't think you should be destructuring the return from the selector.

@Scott Z thanks for your response...now the errors went away but still is printing empty. can you let me know how to fix it https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/yxtwjg?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Fhabits-list.tsx%3A8%2C16-8%2C22

This is because you haven't included the HabbitList component in the App.
Make the following changes to your app.tsx;
First import the component.
import HabitList from "./components/habits-list";

And then include that component in the <App> just below the <AddHabitForm />
  <AddHabitForm />
  <HabitList/> 


Insert the HabitList into the App computer.
Also, currently, the function inside the useSelector doesn't return anything. You should remove those parentheses.
Here's the updated the code
habits-list.tsx
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "../store/store";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";

const HabitList: React.FC = () => {
  const { habits } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.habits);
  return <Box>{console.log("habits", habits)}</Box>;
};

export default HabitList;

App.tsx
import "./styles.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store/store";
import { Container, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import AddHabitForm from "./components/add-habit-form";
import HabitList from "./components/habits-list";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Container maxWidth="md">
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h2" align="center">
          Habit Tracker
          <AddHabitForm />
          <HabitList/> 
        </Typography>
      </Container>
    </Provider>
  );
}


@Anthony S thanks for your response...now the errors went away but still is printing empty. can you let me know how to fix it https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/yxtwjg?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Fhabits-list.tsx%3A8%2C16-8%2C22

@Ram01 I'm seeing the log on console. what else do you want?

@Ram01 Just checked the code, I think habits.push(newHabit) is missing on addHabit reducer.

Yes this is correct, a reducer function needs to return state.  Your addHabbit reducer creates a newHabbit but doesn't return it with state.
